# Find the asymptotic running time of the following code sections

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Find the asymptotic running time of the following code sections. The answer should be the terms of O and Theta.

[image]

I thought about, Theta(n^(1.5)),But im not sure about this.
What do you think ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question, but is rather academic in nature .

Comment: If the answer helped, please feel free to upvote and accept the answer. See how to upvote an answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow and how to accept an answer ---> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs for n<sup>1/2</sup>(square-root of n) times for each iteration of the outer-loop.

The outer-loop runs for n times.

So, the net complexity of running the program would be O(n*n<sup>1/2</sup>) = O(n<sup>3/2</sup>) = O(n<sup>1.5</sup>).

Also, since providing a tighter bound would round it up to Big-Theta(n<sup>1.5</sup>)  time complexity.

So, the time-complexity of the code = ***Θ(n^1.5)***.